# CTD in Helgen (vanilla)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues, mods

I'm constantly crashing in Helgen, right after Alduin shouts.
I first had the unofficial patches, SkyUI and Racemenu installed, and soon uninstalled them because I thought one of those mods was causing the CTD. Turns out I'm still crashing in vanilla.

Comment: Either you aren't running vanilla, or you are playing a save game from before you unusually the mods, because there are a couple mods mentioned in the log, for example Build Your Own House.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've never installed that mod... Weird.

Comment: Uninstall the game, make sure directory are empty, reinstall, patch, and start a new game.

Comment: @JohnLaviolette As far as I can tell, "Build your Own House"/BYOH is the internal name for the Hearthfire DLC, just like DLC1 is Dawnguard and DLC2 is Dragonborn.

Comment: Are you actually starting a new game or just loading the pre-character-select autosave?

Answer (score 1):

**Do all of these steps in order from top to bottom and see if that helps**:

- Lower down your settings
- Disable all the mods you have
- Verify integrity of game cache (if you're on steam)
- Load another save or start a new game
- Uninstall the game completely and install it
- Scan for viruses with your anti-virus program
- Buy new computer specs

If you have tried all of these and have failed then im not sure what to do next.